# Simple Deform not acting as expected

Tags: modeling

When I use the simple deform modifier the results are not at all what I would expect.

To reproduce.

Open new file

create an empty arrows, move that object along the x axis by 2

take the default cube, go into edit mode, stretch it along the y axis by 2

subdivide by 4 times to add extra cuts.

apply simple deform modifier to the cube, with the axis origin as the arrows.

set axis to z.

Select bend.

Now the object is pointing off in a direction which is related to the arrows but not pointing at them. it is not bending around the arrows so the arrows are not the axis but some deformed location of those arrows.

my goal is to bend objects around an axis with a single modifier, am I using the wrong tool?

[image]